# ARM VLD neon structured load

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I am trying to load from an float array into the d registers of the neon unit, in order to later use the q registers for simd. I want to later work on 4 float values at the same time.

Here is what I am doing:

r7 holds the reference to the array

```
VLD2.32 {d0,d2}, [r7]
add r7, r7, #4
VLD2.32 {d1,d3}, [r7]
add r7, r7, #4
```

but when I debug the whole thing nothing gets loaded and the registers are still 0.

The array is structured like this:

[A0,
B0,
A1,
B1,
A2,
B2,
.
.
.]

I want them to be in the registers as followed:

q0 = A0, A1, A2, A3

q1 = B0, B1, B2, B3

Can't seem to get it right, some new input might help. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: why not use vld2.32 {q0,q1},[r7]! instead? If you're loading 16 bytes in your vld instruction, then you need to increment your pointer by 16, not 4. In the example I gave, r7 will be incremented by 32.

Comment: i thought it is notpossible to load to q0 register since in the arm documentation they always use d registers

Comment: I think the compiler is smart enough to split it into multiple D register loads if q register instruction doesn't exist. Give it a try and see.

Comment: they still stay 0 with your loading method and adding 32

Comment: Sounds like your other code has errors as well. Please post a testable problem.

Comment: I changed my whole code to not use structured load ;/ but it's working now